# Run Jquery Function on Page Load and on Keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been googling this for a while, and can't seem to find an answer :( Simply I have two JQuery functions right now:

```
$('#textareainput').keyup(function(){
    //Stuff
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Stuff
});
```

And I would like to combine the two because they have the same exact contents. So how would I go about combining the two? Something like this?

```
$(document,'#textareainput').keyup(function(){
    /stuff
});
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems like you are not understanding the purpose of $(document).ready(function(){});. It makes sure that your Javascript code inside the function will not run until the DOM is completely loaded. When using jQuery, this is almost always the first line in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trigger the event manually after registering the handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#textareainput').keyup(function () {
        //Stuff
    }).keyup();
});
```

But note that, the keyup event related specific properties of the event won't be populated

Comment: Oh, thank you! Now I kind of feel stupid for not realizing xD Thank You again!